# angularjs input field not updating after calling $(".myItem").dateInput()

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

My angular input fields are working fine, until I have a datetime editor.

```
<input class="myItem" defaultdate="2017-05-10T06:50" displayformat="dd-mm-jjjj uu:mm" pageupdownweek="true" updownnavigateminutes="15" isodate="2017-02-28T06:50" ng-if="rule.dataType == 'datetime-local'" ng-model="rule.data" /> {{rule.data}}
```

This code works fine. It shows an input field with a date and next to it is the value as in the input field.

But because I want to use it as a datetime editor, I execute $(".myItem").dateInput(); After this my input field works fine, it works like how it's designed as date time editor. But the {{rule.data}} won't update anymore. Any ideas how I can solve this issue?

https://jsfiddle.net/qn37dg7c/

**Solution:** http://jsfiddle.net/w6afdw1L/

Comment: Stop using jquery and angular at the same time?

Comment: In that case, my input field is not working as how it should work.

Comment: And that is what? You haven't defined how it should work, nor how it doesn't work currently.

Comment: A date time editor in format: "dd-mm-jjjj uu:mm", changing day, month, year, hour and minute with key up and key down. Don't allow dates like 31st of February.

Answer (score 1):

when using `jquery`, it will run out of angular's scope, you have to run `$scope.$apply()` to let angular rerender the page.

```
$(".myItem").dateInput(...);
$scope.$apply();
```

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.change = function() {
      console.log('change event fired');
      $timeout(function() {
        $(".myItem").dateInput();
        $scope.$apply();
      })
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input class="myItem" defaultdate="2017-05-10T06:50" displayformat="dd-mm-jjjj uu:mm" pageupdownweek="true" updownnavigateminutes="15" isodate="2017-02-28T06:50" ng-model="rule.data" ng-change="change()" /> {{rule.data}}
</div>
```

Comment: note: this is supposed to be the right approach, but in case it doesn't work properly, you can try to do the `$apply()` or assign the value in an event, like `change` for example

Comment: It's still not updating. I added ng-change="$scope.$apply();" to my input field. I also added this: $(".myItem").dateInput();
                                $scope.$apply();
                                scope.$apply();

Comment: @user1408786 you have to call `$scope.$apply()` in your controller. change to `ng-change="change()"` and call `$scope.$apply()` in `change` function.

Comment: I changed it to that. But as soon as $(".myItem").dateInput(); has been called the change method is not called anymore.
scope.change = function () {
                            alert("Hello world");
                            $(".myItem").dateInput();
                            $scope.$apply();
                        };

The first time I change something, an alert with hello world will show up, but after that not anymore.

Comment: @user1408786 calling $apply in ng-change will cause digest problem. I have a make a example for you with `$timeout` to avoid it which looks strange any way.

Comment: actually it was the contrary that i meant, something like `$(".myItem").on('change', $scope.$apply);`, or directly simulating the binding behaviour: `$(".myItem").on('change', function(){ $scope.$myVar = $(this).value; });` (written quickly, sorry if there are mistakes). Just that jQuery event should still fire when angular one doesn't anymore.

Comment: @pengyy thanks for your reply, I'm trying to get the $timeout variable into my code but it appears to be undefined. Any ideas how I can get it working there? (Sorry, I'm new to angularjs)

Comment: @user1408786  inject `$timeout` to your controller. please refer my example.

Comment: I'm trying to but the problem is, I have a directive instead of a controller. (see my first post which I edited.)

Comment: @user1408786 you can inject `$timeout` to directive too with the same way.

Comment: I got the $timeout working, but my variable is still not updating.

Comment: @user1408786 can you make a simple plunker or jsfidle to reprocude your problem. since I don't know very well about `dateInput()`

Comment: @user1408786 I have seen your plunker and thanks for making plunker up. and I find that somehow `dateInpue` clears all event bind to it and I guess it's adding new events.

Comment: Is there a way to reset the default binding events? For example on leave?

Comment: @user1408786 maybe you can wrap the input with a `div`, and reset bindings there. but somehow sounds strange.

Comment: @user1408786 that's awesome. good learn. you can post an answer to let others know.